# Remove the backlight when hovering the cursor over the selection

Tags: html, css

I have a registration form, and in it, when you hover the cursor over the selection of a hint to fill in the input, an extra sub-panel appears, which differs in style from the input field:

[image]

register.html:

```
{% extends "shared/index.html" %} 


{% block content %}

<div class="container"> 
  <div class="register">
    <h2>Sign up</h2>
    <div class="errors">
        {% for error in errors %}
          <li>{{error}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <form method="POST">
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" required="required" value="{{username}}" name="username">
        <span>Username</span>
        <i></i>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" required="required" value="{{email}}" name="email">
        <span>Email</span>
        <i></i>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="password" required="required" value="{{password}}" name="password">
        <span>Password</span>
        <i></i>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="password" required="required" value="{{confirm_password}}" name="confirm_password">
        <span>Confirm password</span>
        <i></i>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" href="/confirm-email">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

register style:

```
<style>

@media only screen and (max-width:1220px) { 
    .block { display: block; }
}

.container {
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.container .register {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 50px 40px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.56);
  border-radius: 20px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .register h2{
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.container .register .inputBox{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.container .register .inputBox input{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #23242a;
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 10;
}

.container .register .inputBox span{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 0px 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #8f8f8f;
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .register .inputBox input:valid ~ span,
.container .register .inputBox input:focus ~ span{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  transform: translateY(-34px);
}

.container .register .inputBox i{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 409px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container .register .inputBox input:valid ~ i,
.container .register .inputBox input:focus ~ i{
  height: 44px;
}

.container .register input[type="submit"]{
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.container .register input[type="submit"]:hover{
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}

.container .register input[type="submit"]:active{
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.container .register .errors{
  color: rgb(255, 23, 23);
}

</style>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Feroch</title>
  
  <!-- stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/css/style.css" type="text/css"/>

  <!-- poppins -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
   rel="stylesheet"
   integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl"
   crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
    body {
      background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(20, 10, 0, 0.7), 
      rgba(95, 42, 68, 0.7)
      ), url("/static/images/3187.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: 900px;
    }
  </style>

  {% block title %}
  {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
  {% include "components/navbar.html" %}

  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" 
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  {% block scripts %}
  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Tried to use .input-text:focus{outline:none;}, input:focus{outline: none !important;} in styles, but nothing came out.
I also used this css:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  border: 1px solid green;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: green;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #000 inset;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

But it didn't work out either.
I'll tell you right away I don't want to disable autofill, I just need to leave it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `background` and set `padding` to `10px` for input.
and add `input:-webkit-autofill, input:-webkit-autofill:hover,  input:-webkit-autofill:focus,  input:-webkit-autofill:active{ -webkit-background-clip: text; }`

right now the backgroud in autofill mode disappear but this work only when your input has value.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(20, 10, 0, 0.7), rgba(95, 42, 68, 0.7)), url("/static/images/3187.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1220px) {
  .block {
    display: block;
  }
}

.container {
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.container .register {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 50px 40px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.56);
  border-radius: 20px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .register h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.container .register .inputBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.container .register .inputBox input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #23242a;
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 10;
}

.container .register .inputBox span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 0px 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #8f8f8f;
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .register .inputBox input:valid~span,
.container .register .inputBox input:focus~span {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  transform: translateY(-34px);
}

.container .register .inputBox i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 409px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container .register .inputBox input:valid~i,
.container .register .inputBox input:focus~i {
  height: 44px;
}

.container .register input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.container .register input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}

.container .register input[type="submit"]:active {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.container .register .errors {
  color: rgb(255, 23, 23);
}

input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active{
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="register">
    <h2>Sign up</h2>
    <div class="errors">
      {% for error in errors %}
      <li>{{error}}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <form method="POST">
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" required="required" value="{{username}}" name="username">
        <span>Username</span>
        <i></i>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" required="required" value="{{email}}" name="email">
        <span>Email</span>
        <i></i>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="password" required="required" value="{{password}}" name="password">
        <span>Password</span>
        <i></i>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="password" required="required" value="{{confirm_password}}" name="confirm_password">
        <span>Confirm password</span>
        <i></i>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" href="/confirm-email">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In principle, this solved small problems, not completely of course. But at least I already know which direction to move in, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [`autocomplete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) attribute on [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) elements?

> The [`autocomplete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) attribute takes as its value a space-separated string that describes what, if any, type of autocomplete functionality the input should provide.

In this case, you need to use the `off` value.

```html
<form method="POST">
    <div class="inputBox">
        <input type="text" required="required" autocomplete="off" name="username" />
        <span>Username</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: On the contrary, I need to leave autocomplete enabled

Comment: @Rauf44 As you wish, this is just a practical solution. Also, `autocomplete` has more values than just `off`, so you might want to check that too.